# Display the results of a form submit on the same page just under the form

Tags: 7, forms, search

I have created a form and it takes in 3 values which are Brand, Item and Zipcode. The values are queried and the results are fetched the database table. I want the results to be shown in a table

```
function form_example_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
$sql3 = /*my select query*/

$result = db_query($sql3);
$records = $result->fetchAll();

//code to display table

 echo "<table border=1>";
   echo"<tr>";
    echo"<th>Retail Accounts</th>";
    echo"<th>Address</th>";
    echo"<th>City</th>";
    echo"<th>State</th>";
   echo "</tr>";
   foreach ($records as $record) {
    $record     = get_object_vars($record);
    echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>";
        echo $record['Retail Accounts'];
      echo "</td>";
      echo "<td>";
        echo $record['ADDR'];
      echo "</td>";
      echo "<td>";
        echo $record['CITY'];
      echo "</td>";
      echo "<td>";
        echo $record['STATE'];
      echo "</td>";
    echo"</tr>";    
}
echo "</table>";
}
```

The result is properly fetched but not displayed on the page.

I tried `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` but it displays the result on top of the page.

I want the result to be visible just below my form. How can I achieve that?

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't do the query in the form submit. When you request a rebuild in a form submit the form is built again, but then $form_state is filled with submitted values with which you can query the database and add the result at the end of $form. The absence of submitted values indicate you have a fresh form build and then you don't add the results.

Comment: @4k4 can you help me rebuild the code?

Comment: It's simple, the only thing you do in form submit is set rebuild. Then at the end of your form build: `if (isset($form_state['values']) ) { $form['results'] = ... }` is the place where you query the database and display the results.

Comment: Thank you @4k4. Let me try that and post my findings here

Comment: @4k4. It tried and still the table prints on top of the page

Comment: Did you put the result in $form? For example `$form['results'] = ['#markup' => '<table> ... </table>'];`.

Comment: Here is what I had put `$form['result_table'] = array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#prefix' => '<table>',
        '#markup' => '<tr><th>Retail Accounts</th><th>Address</th><th>City</th><th>State</th></tr>',
      );`

and loops the row using foreach. but only one row is visible now. not the remaining

Comment: @4k4. Thank you so much. I have managed to get the output. I'll post it here

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment the SQl query were made on the hook_form and the hook_form_submit contains only the `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;`. Detailed code is as follows:

```
function form_example_form($form, &$form_state) {

//your form fields or items

$form['submit_button'] = array(
 '#type' => 'submit',
 '#prefix' => '<div class="button-wrapper">',
 '#suffix' => '</div>',
 '#value' => t('Find my store'),
 '#attributes' => array('class' => array('btn btn-primary')),
);


/*-----Query database code Start--------*/

if(isset($form_state['values']['item-name'])){
  //get the values to variable
}

if(isset($zip_code)){


//setup the sql query


if(isset($sql3)){
  $result = db_query($sql3);
}
$records = $result->fetchAll();
$tot_records = count($records);
}

if(isset($tot_records)){
 if($tot_records>0){ 

  $form['result_table'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#prefix' => '<table border=0 class="table table-bordered">',
    '#markup' => '<tr><th>Store Name</th><th>Address</th><th>City</th><th>State</th></tr>',
  );

  $i=0; $j=0;  
  foreach ($records as $record) {

    $record_in_array = json_decode(json_encode($records[$i]), true); //Convert object to array

    $form[$j]['result_table1']= array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<tr>',
    );      

    $form[$j]['result_table2']= array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#prefix' => '<td>',
      '#suffix' => '</td>',
      '#markup' => $record_in_array['sql column name1'],
    );
    $form[$j]['result_table3']= array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#prefix' => '<td>',
      '#suffix' => '</td>',
      '#markup' => $record_in_array['sql column name2'],
    );
    $form[$j]['result_table4']= array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#prefix' => '<td>',
      '#suffix' => '</td>',
      '#markup' => $record_in_array['sql column name3'],
    );
    $form[$j]['result_table5']= array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#prefix' => '<td>',
      '#suffix' => '</td>',
      '#markup' => $record_in_array['sql column name4'],
    );


    $form[$j]['result_table6']= array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '</tr>',
    );

    $i++;
    $j++;
  }

  $form['result_table7']= array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#suffix' => '</table>',
  );

  }      
 }

/*-----End Query database code--------*/

return $form;

 }

 function form_example_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
 }
```

Hope this helps!